# EXTJS 4.1 How can I put a button next a fieldlabel of an textfield?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, extjs, textfield

I have an textfield like this:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
fieldLabel: 'To',
id: 'mailTo',
name: 'mailTo',
```

The layout of my form:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
}
```

The red rectangle is where I want to put my button.

[image: example]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as a workaround/alternative you could put a button with that same label, then as your next item under that you could put a textbox without a label.  It would probably achieve the same result and would be relatively simple.